# How to implement a closure in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, closures

I don't know much about jQuery. Here I am trying to implement a closure to attach a click event to each anchor tag so that each of them will alert a certain number once blicked. But I am getting the following error:

> ```
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
>
> };})(i);
> ```

can anyone help me with this problem?thanks :)

Code:

```
<div id='pageBox'>
    <ul id='pageContainer'>
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=$pagenum;$i++){?>
           <li><a href=''><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
 </div>
<script>
for(i=1;i<=<?php echo $pagenum;?>;i++){

      $('#pageContainer li a').click((function(i){return function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               alert(i);
            };})(i);
      );

}
```

Comment: The last `);` should be `});` of `click`

Comment: are you sure about that..? last ) is for click event

Comment: With the loop you are using you will be creating duplicate event listeners for the same elements. @Satpal has the best solution, that is worth investigating as you are learning javascript and will use it consistently when passing values from php to javascript

Comment: Actually, the real cause of your syntax error is that there's an extra `;` at the end of `};})(i);`. That `(function(i){...` thing is not a stand-alone statement, but an argument to `.click()`, and so should not be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need closure here. This can be achieved using simple approach. Persist php variable `$i` in `data-*` prefixed custom attribute, which can be fetch using `.data()`

Change your HTML as

```
<ul id='pageContainer'>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$pagenum;$i++){?>
       <li><a href='' data-id='<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
```

Script

```
  $('#pageContainer li a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('id'));
  });
```

Comment: i thought about that..but as i am learning i prefer to stick to my approach :)

Comment: @AL-zami, Its upto you which ever approach suits you follow that. I still have some doubts with your approach.